# Upgraded to Eclipse 3.7 - IBM ClearCase plugin started to hangs on connection to ClearCase with high CPU

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, clearcase

There was no hanging in Eclipse 3.5 with the same Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter 7.6.0.v201105111445

Answering ongoing questions: JDK 6, ClearCase, Windows XP 32 bits.

Comment: What version of jdk are you using to execute and launch your new eclipse?

Comment: And are we talking about ClearCase or CCRC? Are you on a 64-bits plattform?

Comment: You can also use the suggestions at http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/How_to_report_a_deadlock to find out where the JVM is spending its time.